# In React native App is not opening from background

Tags: reactjs, push-notification

in react native i am using notifee library for notications .when app is in kill state or background state app is not opening on the click of notification how to resolve this . its working fine when app is in foreground state

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am unable to add code here please give me example so that i can refer it